# Generating dSYM while publishing XCFramework with Kotlin Cocoapod plugin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native, xcframework, dsym

I am using Kotlin (1.7.0) [native.cocoapods](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-cocoapods.html) and I expected it to generate a [.dSYM](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-ios-symbolication.html#producing-dsym-for-release-kotlin-binaries). I am using, based on the documentation:

```
targets.withType<KotlinNativeTarget> {
    binaries.all {
        freeCompilerArgs = freeCompilerArgs + "-Xadd-light-debug=enable"
    }
    binaries.withType<Framework> {
        isStatic = true
    }
}
```

However the task `podPublishReleaseXCFramework` generates a pod but not a `.dSYM` directory. Where is it expected to be generated?

Comment: What version of Kotlin do you use? It was fixed in 1.6.20. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-49484

Comment: I am using 1.7.0, so theoretically that should be fixed. In which `build` directory should the `.dSYM` appear?

Comment: Created a new issue for it https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-53866